# Get a matrix of the number of "periods" with non-na values between all column pairs (joint count)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statistics

Pandas features the `.corr()` and `.cov()` functions which generate correlation matrices and covariance matrices respectively. It is possible to pass `min_periods=<some int>` to any of them as to yield `NaN` as the correlation or covariance for any column pair which has too few rows with non-nan values in both columns. I seek the best way to generate a matrix which gives the actual number of shared non-nan numeric values across all column pairs.

**For example:**

*Set up*

```
pd.np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.random.randn(20, 3),
                  columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df.loc[df.index[:5], 'a'] = pd.np.nan
df.loc[df.index[5:10], 'b'] = pd.np.nan
```

*I desire to get a counts_df such as:*

```
    a   b   c
a  15  10  15
b  10  15  15
c  15  15  20
```

*I can do that with the following code:*

```
counts = []
for i in df.columns:
    for j in df.columns:
        counts.append((i, j, df[[i, j]].dropna().count().iloc[0]))
counts_df = pd.DataFrame(counts, columns=['i', 'j', 'count']).set_index(['i', 'j']).unstack()
```

It goes without saying that the code does at least twice the job it would have to, but that is not the point. It is probably not a good solution to begin with. The code is very slow for large datasets (1000+ columns and 100 rows) even though `.corr()` is run in an instance on the same frame. I am not very surprised that this is the case, however, I haven't been able to think of a way to have pandas generate the "count matrix". What would be a smart/good/clean/quick way to generate such a count matrix with pandas? There's probably something built in that I just haven't thought about...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> tmp = df.notna().astype(int)
>>> counts_df = tmp.T.dot(tmp)
>>> counts_df
    a   b   c
a  15  10  15
b  10  15  15
c  15  15  20
```

Comment: Oh my, that is so neat and makes so much sense. Thanks a bunch!